# How do I extract two different keywords from two different lines in a file in bash shell?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file called data.txt. when I read the file, the content looks like the below.

```
$ cat data.txt 
name: linuxVol
id: 6
type: Linux
dir excludes: .snapshot*
              ~snapshot*
              .zfs
              .isilon
              .ifsvar
              .lustre
inode: 915720
free_space: 35.6TiB (auto)
total_capacity: 95.0TiB (auto)
number_of_files: 5,789,643
number_of_dirs: 520,710
mounts: https://server1.example.com:30002: /mnt/tube
```

How can I extract keywords `Linux` from the third line and `server1.example.com` from the last line and then represent them in the same line separated by space? The output should show something like below

```
Linux server1.example.com
```

I tried to do something like this but not sure how could I extract `server1.example.com`

```
cat data.txt | egrep "type|mounts" | awk '{print $NF}' | tr "\n" " "
```

output was:

```
Linux /mnt/tube
```

My expected output:

```
Linux server1.example.com
```

Solving it with AWK/SED will work for me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are just two lines in the file, one with `type:` and another with `mount:` and they come in a set order, you can use

```sh
awk '/type:|mounts:/{gsub(/https?:\/\/|:.*/, "", $2); a = (length(a)==0 ? "" : a " ") $2} END{print a}' file
```

If a line contains `type:` or `mounts:`, the `http://` or `https://` and all text after `:` are removed from Field 2, and then the value is either assigned to `a` or appended with a space to `a`, and once there is an end of file, the `a` value is printed.

*Details*:

- `/type:|mounts:/` - find lines containng `type:` or `mounts:`
- `gsub(/https?:\/\/|:.*/, "", $2)` - removes `http://`, `https://` or `:` and the rest of the string from Field 2 value
- `a = (length(a)==0 ? "" : a " ") $2` - assign `a` + space + Field 2 value to `a` if `a` is not empty, if it is, just assign Field 2 value to `a`
- `END{print a}` - at the end of the file processing, print `a` value.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/YZdwdL):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='name: linuxVol
id: 6
type: Linux
dir excludes: .snapshot*
              ~snapshot*
              .zfs
              .isilon
              .ifsvar
              .lustre
inode: 915720
free_space: 35.6TiB (auto)
total_capacity: 95.0TiB (auto)
number_of_files: 5,789,643
number_of_dirs: 520,710
mounts: h''ttps://server1.example.com:30002: /mnt/tube'

awk '/type:|mounts:/{gsub(/https?:\/\/|:.*/, "", $2); a = (length(a)==0 ? "" : a " ") $2} END{print a}' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
Linux server1.example.com
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `gnu-awk` you could also set the field separator to `:` followed by 1 or more spaces.

Then check the first field for type or mounts, and for mounts use a capture group to get the part after the https:// part

Given that the order of the lines is the same, and both keywords are present, you can concat the values.

```
awk -F ":[[:space:]]+" '
$1 == "type" {s = $2}
$1 == "mounts" && match($2, /https?:\/\/([^[:space:]:]+)/, a) {s = s " " a[1]}
END {print s}
' data.txt
```

Output

```
Linux server1.example.com
```

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you have tag-value pairs in your input I find it best to create an array (`f[]` below) to hold those mappings and then you can access the values by indexing that array with the tags:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    tag = val = $0
    sub(/:.*/,"",tag)
    sub(/[^:]+: */,"",val)
    f[tag] = val
}
END {
    sub("[^:]+://","",f["mounts"])
    sub(/:.*/,"",f["mounts"])
    print f["type"], f["mounts"]
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk data.txt
Linux server1.example.com
```

The above would need a minor tweak if you also wanted to handle the multi-line value for the `dir excludes` tag but as written it gives you the ability to read/test/print all other values by their tags.

Answer (score 3):

I think a `sed` solution is also needed

```
$ sed -n '/type:/{s/[^ ]* \(.*\)/\1/;h;d};/mounts:/{s|[^/]*//\([^:]*\).*|\1|;x;G;s/\n/ /p}' input_file
Linux server1.example.com
```

Or as a script

```
$ cat script.sed
/type:/ {                     #Match line with `type:`     
    s/[^ ]* \(.*\)/\1/        #Extract the word `Linux`
    h                         #Retain it in the hold sapce
    d                         #Delete the line
}
/mounts:/ {                   #Match line with `mounts:`
    s|[^/]*//\([^:]*\).*|\1|  #Extract the URL
    x                         #Exchange the contents of the hold space for the URL
    G                         #Append the URL
    s/\n/ /p                  #Remove the new line
}
```

```
$ sed -nf script.sed input_file
Linux server1.example.com
```

Comment: Thank you @HatLess! Could you please explain this command a little bit other than the RegEx that you used?

Comment: @mht.haque Sure. Please check edit